# Marker on top of the menu list items

Tags: css, menu, nav, marker

How can i create a marker that appears on top of  the menu list items when i hover over them ?Like the one they have [here](http://www.bershka.com/ro/en/) .
It's possible to create with only css ?

EDIT:I don't want the code from you , i just want some tips because i don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of what you want to achieve. The most important parts are the `:before` pseudo element and the `position: relative` of `<a>`. Please notice that the width of those "markers" is the `width` property of your pseudo element. (In this case it's 2px). Here is the CSS-Part of the marker pseudo element.

```
a:hover:before {
    content:"";
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute; /* Only works well when the parent is 'position:relative' */
    left: 50%;
    top: -10px;
}
```

**Minimal Example Snippet**

```css
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li > a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
a:hover:before {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple navigation along the lines of:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

...then you can create a basic hover effect using the `:hover` CSS pseudo-class:

```
ul li a:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking just CSS, have a look at the [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) pseudo class.

This can be combined with `visiblity` to create something like this:

```css
span {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p><span>| </span>hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this only CSS:

CSS

```
    .menu-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
}
.menu-wrap div{
    position:relative;
    margin-top:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    padding:10px;
    }
.menu-wrap div:hover:before{
    content:'|'; /*--------you can put image here as marker*/
    position:absolute;
    bottom:40;
    font-size:1.3em;
    margin-left:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap">              
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
  <div class="menu-item"></div>
</div>
```

See if it is what you want.